# How is "<" defined for class in ruby in term of inheritance?

Tags: ruby, class, struct

What happen exactly when you inherit from `Struct.new` instead from a class? Or in other word, how is the `<` operator defined for class when used with struct objects instead of class objects?

Case 1:

```
class SomeClass < ParentClass; end;
```

Case 2:

```
AClass = Struct.new(:value)
class SubClass < AClass; end;
```

Case 3:

```
class SubClass < Struct.new(:value); end;
```

Comment: _how is the < operator defined for class when used with struct objects instead of class objects?_ - Why are you thinking `<` is different in case of `Struct`?

Comment: a `Struct` is a class. `pry(main)> Struct.new(:value).class
=> Class`

Comment: In Case 3 (after you add `end`): `class SubClass < Struct.new(:value); end;  SubClass.superclass #=> #<Class:0x007fef230b8d98>; SubClass < SubClass.ancestors[1] #=> true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is exactly zero difference between those three cases. In all three cases, the right operand of `<` is an expression, that, when evaluated returns a `Class`. In case 1 and 3, it's a constant that gets dereferenced, in case 2, it's a method call.

Despite Ruby's apparent complexity, it *is* more regular than you think.

Answer (score 3):

#### Case 1:

This is standard inheritance that doesn't involve a struct. I'm not sure what you would like to know about this.

#### Case 2:

Struct.new returns a class that has the attributes given to the initialize method. For example, the following struct and Foo class behave the same.

```
Struct.new(:bar, baz)

class Foo
  attr_reader :bar, :baz

  def initialize(bar, baz)
    @bar = bar
    @baz = baz
  end
end
```

Since the above struct and class have the same behavior, inheriting from them would give the subclass that functionality.

```
class Bar < Struct.new(:bar, :baz)
end

bar_struct = Bar.new('hello', 'world')
bar_struct.bar # => 'hello'
bar_struct.baz # => 'world'

class Bar < Foo
end

bar_class = Bar.new('hello', 'world')
bar_class.bar # => 'hello'
bar_class.baz # => 'world'
```

#### Case 3:

This is identical to case 2. The only difference here is that you have assigned the struct to the constant `AClass`

Comment: In your first code example under Case 2, I believe you want `attr_accessor` instead of `attr_reader` in `class Foo`. A class inheriting from a struct allows its attributes to be read and set.